# Determine if there is a cross reference using idapython given a specific address

Tags: ida, idapython, script

I want to end up in something like the following using idapython to determine if given a specific address there is an xref (without caring where the XREF comes from)

```
ea_start = #
ea_end = #
for ea in range(ea_start,ea_end):
    if hasXREF(ea):
        doSomething()


def hasXREF(addr):
    
    if [something]:
        return true
    else
        return false
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this link: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idautils-module.html#XrefsTo

You can use the function:
`XrefsTo(ea, flags=0)`.

From the description, it
`Return all references to address ea`.

And `XrefsFrom(ea, flags=0)`, which  `Return all references from address 'ea'`

You should have anything for your script now :)

I have an example of a working IDA Python script that you can use as a reference here (It count the number of XrefTo per functions of a binary): https://github.com/GuillaumeOrlando/MalwareAnalysisArtifacts/blob/master/IDA_Scripts/XrefChecker.py.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [*flags*](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/group___f_f__.html) which are attached to each address and, among other info, store information about whether the address has any xrefs to it.

```
def hasXREF(addr):        
    return has_xref(get_flags(addr))
```

BTW, instead of inspecting every address it's better and faster to inspect only head bytes (starts of instructions or data items) which are returned by the [`idautils.Heads()`](https://www.hex-rays.com/wp-content/static/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idautils-module.html#Heads) iterator.